# Faster way of adding up outer products across columns of matrix

Tags: numpy, vectorization

```
sum_v=np.zeros([d,d])
for i in range(num):
    sum_v+=np.outer(v[:,i],v[:,i])
```

Faster way of adding up outer products across columns of matrix, where matrix is v. 
Thus, faster way of adding up matrices when taking outer product along columns of another matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `matrix-multiplication` with its transposed version -

```
v.dot(v.T)
```

**Explanation :** You are basically performing `v[:,None,:]*v[None,:,:]` (if you print the outer product result at each iteration and study it) and then `sum-reducing` along the last axis of the product. Stepping back and looking from the input array's point of view, we are performing element-wise multiplication between two versions of `v`, such that the last axis would be kept aligned and finally `sum-reduced`, while the leftover two axes would *spread_out* as two axes of the final result. That `sum-reduction` is basically `matrix-multiplication` between `v` and its transpose.

Comment: why is this the same? Where are you summing?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Added few comments on it. See if they help/make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Einstein summation notation, `np.einsum` can make visualization easier:

```
sum_v = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', v, v)
```

which is the same as:

```
sum_v = np.einsum('ik,kj->ij`, v, v.T)
```

As @Divakar points out, `np.einsum('ik,kj->ij', ...)` is functionally equivalent to (and slower than) `np.dot(...)`